# Strange IOError when time.sleep() in Python

Tags: python, ioerror

So I have a pretty strange error when using time.sleep() in Python.

```
start = time.time()
# some code goes here
end = time.time()
spent = end - start
time.sleep(1.0101 - spent) # this gives a strange IOError...
```

Can I fix it? I can't change spent or 1.0101.
EDIT: The error is: IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument.
EDIT2: I'm using a Raspberry Pi 2.

Comment: can you please edit your question to include the exact error?

Comment: what if spent is bigger than 1.0101 ?

Comment: @JosephFarah It will take a little bit of time but okay

Comment: @JoranBeasley it's not.

Comment: @JosephFarah I added the error.

Comment: @Ace what values have you been seeing for `spent`?

Comment: @DanGetz I'm testing and the error won't wanna appear half of me is :) and other half is :(

Comment: @DanGetz it's always around 0.0007

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Linux you usually get `IOError` when passing a negative number to `time.sleep`. Some systems may sleep forever instead.

This [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue12459) has been resolved by raising a `ValueError` if a negative value is provided since Python 3.3.

Comment: Thanks, but spent is NEVER bigger than 0.0101. And I can't use 0.011 because the script will be slower and out of sync from the other script.

Comment: Thanks. It was negative.